# I can't mount with mount -a for error wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock but I can mount manually

Tags: ubuntu, mount, xfs, uuid

I usually use UUID to mount my devices, because I use a lot of external ones and so I control it better.
But when I want to mount partitions formatted with XFS I have problems
Generally this works for me

```
UUID=8aa6c0d2-c18e-4606-b1da-f5f1f7617f00 /backups xfs rw,noquota,errors=remount-ro       0       1
```

But sometimes this method fail on `m̀ount -a`

```
❯ sudo mount -a
mount: /backup5t: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

if mount with command below work fine

```
❯ sudo mount -U d7a5fcb4-4c68-4856-9989-f20b780bef66 /backup5t

 ~ ❯
```

#### /etc/fstab

```
UUID=d7a5fcb4-4c68-4856-9989-f20b780bef66 /backup5t xfs rw,noquota,errors=remount-ro  0  1
```

#### blikd

```
❯ sudo blkid | grep UUID | grep BACK
/dev/sdc2: UUID="d7a5fcb4-4c68-4856-9989-f20b780bef66" TYPE="xfs" PARTLABEL="BACKUP5T" PARTUUID="f362e33b-8eb5-49a8-8b62-7ac855475741"
```

Comment: Check `dmesg` for any additional information

Comment: tail -f /var/log/dmesg not show anything after run mount -a

Comment: Thsk. After see your post, tail -f syslog and see error. `Jan 25 12:41:31 nox kernel: [117385.642912] XFS (sdc2): unknown mount option [errors=remount-ro]`

Answer (score 3):

After I see comment of @michael-hampton in Ubuntu 20.04 not see anything on dmesg.

But an idea.

```
tail -f /var/log/dmesg /var/log/syslog
...
Jan 25 12:41:31 nox kernel: [117385.642912] XFS (sdc2): unknown mount option [errors=remount-ro].
```

For **xsf** and external device, the best option is **nofail**

```
UUID=d7a5fcb4-4c68-4856-9989-f20b780bef66 /backup5t xfs rw,noquota,nofail  0  1
```